# Not able to access static files

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have trouble accessing static files when I route my flask application to sub-pages, like `batch\

My code look like :

```
def batch(batch_name):
    try:
        if 'username' in session:
            #something here
            return render_template("batch.html", something = something)
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("500.html", error = str(e))
```

whereas Jinja template is :

```
        <li><a href="batch/{{ batch_name }}">{{ batch_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

It is just working fine when I try to do it like `batch_name`

The output when I run this :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2019 11:27:12] "GET /batch/static/js/json-app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Why this `\batch` adds before `static_url`

I tried

```
        <li><a href="{{ batch_name }}">{{ batch_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

it is working fine but I need my url to be like `http://localhost:5000/batch/Oct-batch` not `http://localhost:5000/Oct-batch`

Comment: You have to use `url_for` instead of generating URLs like that

Comment: How in `render_template()` I'm supposed to use `url_for`. I don't get it

Comment: Easy => `{{ url_for('batch', batch_name=batch_name) }}`

Comment: It's still the same, getting 404 for static files `/batch/static/js/whatever.js`.

Comment: for static files you won't do that :/ `{{ url_for('static', filename='js/whetever.js') }}`

Comment: I hardly recommend you to learn Flask from a good resource like [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Comment: Finally adding a `/` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now I'm breaking my keyboard, just realized I needed to add a `/` in static files url.

Little tweak has changed everything. In my case solution is `app Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css`